# I'm getting truncated zeros for my string values when using invoke('text) in Cypress

Tags: javascript, text, cypress, invoke

Here are my line of codes:

```
cy.get('div.thread-header p.text-secondary.small').invoke('text').then((ticket) => {
    ticketDetails.ticketNumber = ticket
})
return ticketDetails
```

The web element, `div.thread-header p.text-secondary.small`, has a text value of **Ticket #000-0000091**. But when I used `cy.log(ticketDetails.ticketNumber)`, I got **Ticket #91**

The goal is to get the text value as is. Can someone help?

Comment: can you post a screenshot of the html DOM ?

Comment: can you try using invoke('innerHTML')

Answer (score 1):

Your `return ticketDetails` is executing before the `.then()` callback.

Whatever is in `ticketDetails` initially is returned, not the result of `ticketDetails.ticketNumber = ticket`.

For example, if I try this

```js
let ticketDetails = {
  ticketNumber: 'not-set-yet'
}
cy.get('div.thread-header p.text-secondary.small')
  .invoke('text').then((ticket) => {
    ticketDetails.ticketNumber = ticket
    cy.log(ticketDetails.ticketNumber)
  })
cy.log(ticketDetails.ticketNumber)
```

shows two logs with the 2nd one showing the initial value

```
log    Ticket #000-0000091
log    not-set-yet
```

But `cy.log()` outputs in the message is the order called, because they are queued commands which always run in sequence given.

Change to `console.log()` and you can see the true execution order

```js
let ticketDetails = {
  ticketNumber: 'not-set-yet'
}
cy.get('div.thread-header p.text-secondary.small')
  .invoke('text').then((ticket) => {
    ticketDetails.ticketNumber = ticket
    console.log(ticketDetails.ticketNumber)
  })
console.log(ticketDetails.ticketNumber)
```

gives two logs in this order, which shows that the last log executes first

```
not-set-yet
Ticket #000-0000091
```

so your return statement is executing before your assignment.